# VB.NET - Programatically check to see if a Sheet exists in Excel

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, excel

I was wondering if there is a way to programatically check and see if a sheet exsists in an excel workbook?

Basically what I am doing is checking if an excel document exists, opening it up and checking if the specified sheet exists. I am currently unaware as to how to check and see if the sheet exists. Any help would be awesome! Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I have been given some good code to make this work. All i am missing now is the correct imports.

I have searched and found this import :

```
Imports Tools = Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel
```

But for some reason that is not recognized. Do I have to configure VS somehow to make it work? Or am I just using the wrong import?

Comment: You may have to add a reference to the tools DLL to your VS project before you can do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the worksheets collection and iterate and check the name, this is c#

```
foreach (Sheet xlsSheet in xlsxWorkbooks)
{
    if (xlsSheet.Name.equals("NameYouAreLookingFor")) // Maybe add ToLower() incase of case issues
    {
        //Return First Cell Value
    }
}
```

Comment: is there something I have to import for this to work?

Imports Tools = Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel??

Comment: I reference to the interop assembly, I beleive it is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel or something close, sorry I didn't realize you were not using interop

Comment: That's perfectly fine... Thank you very much! My problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

again my example is in C# but this should get what you want.

```
bool sheetExist = false;
OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
objConn.Open();
DataTable dt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
if (dt == null)
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        DataRow[] rows = dt.Select("TABLE_NAME = 'Sheet1$'")
        if (rows != null)
            sheetExist = rows.count > 0
    }
```

Comment: I understand the code now But I am trying to find the correct imports for VB.NET

Answer (score 1):

```
var containsSheet = 
    (workBookIn.Sheets.Cast<object>()
        .Select(sheetValue => sheetValue as Worksheet))
        .Any(workbookSheet => workbookSheet != null && workbookSheet.Name == sheetName);
```